# Running a compiled application with a .mdf database file on another computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, mdf

I received a visual C# application which I have to put on other computers. The application was provided to me as a folder of compiled files (no installer file). I noticed it contains a .mdf file which, as I've read, is a localdb database file.

I know that the application was written in Visual studio 2015. I tried copying it to another computer, where it reported the following error.

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details.

I've read, that I should install localDB or Microsoft SQL Server for such appplication to run.

Is there anything else I should change on the other computer? Will such an application run on an older version of Microsoft SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say with the information given what else you might need to change on the other computers beyond the minimum requirements of whatever .NET version it needs, and SQL Server Express in the LocalDB execution mode. Since the latter is free you might as well install the 2016 version of that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Apart from the info I gave above, I know that the target framework of the application is 3.5. All the computers, which it is supposed to run on, have Windows 7 or later.